# SEO Implications of Skipping Client-Side Routing in Next.js SSR

Tags: next.js, seo, server-side-rendering

```js
const SomePage = () => {
  return <>{/* ... */}</>
}

export default SomePage

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { slug } = context.params

  if (context?.req?.url?.startsWith('/_next')) {
    return {
      props: {},
    }
  }

  const queryClient = new QueryClient()

  await queryClient.fetchQuery([slug], () => getSomeDataBySlug(slug))

  return {
    props: { dehydratedProps: dehydrate(queryClient) },
  }
}
```

The ssr page created this structure to enable caching of react-query

I also thought about declaring a query client outside, but I didn't because I found an issue that in this case, the cache might conflict with another user.

But I have a question.

If you use the userouter to enter the ssr page, the data patching of getserversideprops on that page is skipped.
(Of course, there are other ways to route on the client side other than userouter.)

Does this affect the seo?

Data patching works correctly for refresh/first rendering, etc.
Then, is there no problem with the seo?

I'm so curious!